# Please Unban My Account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ban, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

this is just a message to moderators or users who can unban me.

I misused StackOverflow previously because I was not aware of how to use it properly. I have learnt my lesson and have been answering many questions lately. Some questions people say "thank you" and "this helped" but never tick or upvote. Which seems to annoy me...

Aside from that I am merely 13 years old. I have a current reputation of 347. Over the last week I have increased my reputation by 100+ which is an accomplishement for me. I was banned in the first place for because my answers had no upvotes or ticks or comments. They were not structured well too. I have improved on this.

Thank you for reading, I hope you forgive and unban me! Thanks!

Comment: You are not suspended, are you banned from asking questions? If so, the ban is automatic, there is nothing the moderators or other users can do, you just need to keep providing good answers. Some of your recent answers are upvoted, you are in a good track.

Comment: Ok seems fair eNough... How much rep until I get unbanned?

Comment: @Rohan Kapur: Reputation does not have any influence; only the quality of your posts does. If you're question-banned, it would make sense to start by improving your questions rather than just your answers.

Comment: One suggestion I might make, independent of the question-asking ban, is that you refrain from plagiarizing the content of others. This answer (now deleted, and available only to 10k users): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10413861/19679 was copied word-for-word from two answers and a comment on your previous question without any attribution. Similarly, this answer was copied almost word-for-word from quixoto's previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143453/19679 . Please refrain from doing this in the future.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Who are you, and why aren't you carrying a diamond?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderators can't lift this ban for you; it happens automatically and [only under certain conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Are you still banned from posting new questions on Stack Overflow? Try posting a new question using this same account and see if you still get the same error message.

If you still need assistance, contact team@stackoverflow.com. This has been mentioned to you a number of times—besides improving your existing questions, there is no other recourse.

Comment: Ok... Thanks! I will continue to post answers...