# Shouldn't I be un-question banned now

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)
>   [Please Unban My Account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131163/please-unban-my-account)

My name is Rohan Kapur. You can check out my user profile here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260708/rohan-kapur

Ever since I was question banned, which was a while back when, I wasn't really caring about Stack Overflow or answering questions or really knowing how I should write under the required guidelines.But I have **improved**. I have already emailed the team and they have given me a response that I should get more up votes/answer more questions correctly. When I was question banned around a month ago, my rep was below 100. Now its 613. That is good for me, and my age is only 13.

How much more now? I am on constantly checking to see if I am un-questionbanned but I am still not... what should I do more. I am working on SO hard!

Comment: Checkout this [User](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1343911/prawcha)

Comment: Ok, but whats the relevance of that user. Is it that her questions have up votes... I'll check her questions....

Comment: she is also 13 years old.

Comment: ok ill check her questions out

Comment: + mortarboard bage ;)

Comment: yeah...!!!!!!!!

Comment: Im having the same problem, Ive been banned for a month or 2 now, but I have been really trying to write some quality answers (I am also at a quite young age). Hopefully following this should get me unbanned :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Humm, this may be the first case where I agree with someone asking to be un-questioned banned.  Your questions and answers are not the worst I've seen by far (sure, theres room for improvement, but no-ones perfect, right?)

You can see *none* of your questions (**not a single one**) has an upvote. You should consider going back through these questions and editing them to make them better/ more detailed:

- Indent/ format your code properly
- Add "`" code tags around inline code (class names etc).
- Improve capitalization, paragraphs  etc.

If you do this, people may add upvotes to them when they bump to the front of the site and help you out.

Deleted questions *are* taken into account with the ban, and I can't see your deleted questions (obviously) so I'm not sure how much this is affecting you, but don't just delete bad questions as this won't help you.

Comment: Sure ill do this... but nobody would up vote or see it...

Comment: @RohanKapur: When you edit the post, it'll get bumped up to the top page.

Comment: oh ok, ill do it soon...

Comment: absolutely amazing... THANK YOU! I am un-question banned!

Comment: wow... just rechecked stack overflow... rep now 720!!!!!